# Deleting shapefile using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, shapefile, delete

I'm running an automated process that outputs shapefiles. However, there are these types of files that are not useful, they are garbage, so it is necessary for me to delete them.

I know that in Python the following function deletes **only one file:**

```
import os
os.remove()
```

However, a shapefile is more than a single file (.shx, .dbf, .prj, .cpg).

Using ArcPy, is there a way to delete all the files of a "shapefile"?

Comment: `arcpy.Delete_management` is the tool of choice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already pointed out by others, you can use [**`arcpy.management.Delete`**](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/delete.htm):

```py
import arcpy

file = r"D:\projects\playground\python\stackgis\data\test.shp"

if arcpy.Exists(file) and arcpy.TestSchemaLock(file):
    arcpy.management.Delete(file)
else:
    print(f"Cannot delete {file}.")
    print("The file either doesn't exist or is locked by another application.")
```

[JasonInVegas](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/422946/deleting-shapefile-using-arcpy#comment689810_422949) added a good comment to another answer: make sure that there is no lock on the shapefile through another application.

You can achieve this by using [`arcpy.TestSchemaLock`](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/functions/testschemalock.htm). The function tests if a lock can be acquired and returns `True` if so. If there is already a lock on the data, no lock can be acquired and the function returns `False`.

---

Alternatively, you could use [**GDAL/OGR**](https://gdal.org/):

```py
import os

from osgeo import ogr  # conda install -c conda-forge gdal

shapefile = r"D:\projects\playground\python\stackgis\data\test.shp"

driver = ogr.GetDriverByName("ESRI Shapefile")

if os.path.exists(shapefile):
    driver.DeleteDataSource(shapefile)
```

---

Or, you could write your **own function** to delete the shapefile along with the [associated files](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/shapefiles/shapefile-file-extensions.htm):

```py
import os
from pathlib import PurePath

shapefile_extensions = [
    "shp", "shx", "dbf", "sbn", "sbx", "fbn", 
    "fbx", "ain", "aih", "atx", "ixs", "mxs", 
    "prj", "xml", "cpg"
]

def delete_shapefile(shapefile):
    
    if os.path.exists(shapefile):

        path = PurePath(shapefile)
        os.remove(shapefile)

        for extension in shapefile_extensions:

            associated_file = f"{path.parent}\\{path.stem}.{extension}"
            if os.path.exists(associated_file):
                os.remove(associated_file)


shapefile = r"D:\projects\playground\python\stackgis\data\test.shp"

delete_shapefile(shapefile)
```

**Something to consider:** `delete_shapefile` deletes files based on the shapefile's name and the associated file extensions.

That can lead to an unwanted side effect: If someone names an unrelated XML file (or another file with a shapefile-associated extension) same as the shapefile, that file will be deleted as well.

However, the question would be, does `ogr` and/or `arcpy` do a deep check? I don't know.

Answer (score 3):

To elaborate slightly on @Vince's comment, use `arcpy.Delete_management("C:/path/to/shapefile.shp")` -- the files with other extensions will be automatically removed as well.

Comment: ...be sure that the shapefile(s) are not open in any os-based viewer, file explorer, or software which creates locks on the files, otherwise the arcpy management will raise errors as well as leave you with incomplete deletions.